# I can't compile CGI project to Linux in Lazarus

Tags: linux, cgi, lazarus

I installed Lazarus 1.0.10 and FCL package.

I made a CGI test program to run in my [Hostgator](http://hostgator.com) account but when I compile it I get this error:

> fcllaz.pas(0,0) Fatal: Can not find unit system used by fcllaz.

That if I configure the project to target Linux SO. If I use standard (Windows) it compiles ok, but my hostgator account is Linux.

Does anyone had that kind of problem? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a.s. If you are trying to do crosscompiling, crosscompiling TO linux is an advanced topic. You are better off with installing a similar *nix system as your host in a VM)

FPC is probably not completely installed. Some Ubuntu/debian versions insist on having to do manual configuration afterwards.

Make sure that

1. there is a symlink of $prefix/bin/ppc386   to $prefix/lib/fpc//ppc386
2. make sure there is a /etc/fpc.cfg or ~/.fpc.cfg with a -Fu line in it that points
   to $prefix/lib/fpc/$FPCVERSION/units/$FPCTARGET/*       (in this case FPC will fill in version and target)

where $PREFIX is the prefix where you installed FPC ( typically /usr or /usr/local )

for more information see the [buildfaq](http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/buildfaq.pdf)